# Django How to pass variable from a view to a form view

Tags: django, django-views

I have two models. One is project and another is todo. The todo model has a foreign key that is the related project's id.

I have a template that displays the individual project and generates a link to a form to add a todo list. How do I pass the project id to the todo form?

I guess I could simply pass the project id in the URL but is that the best way?

My current views.py

```
class CompanyProjectsDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Project
    id = Project.objects.only('id')
    template_name = 'company_accounts/project_detail.html'

class TodoCreateView(CreateView):
    model = ProjectTodo
    template_name = 'company_accounts/add_todo.html'
    fields = ['title', 'notes', 'status']
```

Here is my template:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

  {% block content %}
  <h1>Add Todo</h1>
   <form action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="save">
   </form>
  {% endblock content %}
```

To check to see if the project id is being passed to the form I have tried {{ project.id }} in the template and several other things that have not worked.

Comment: Share with us what you have done so far to address this issue?

Comment: I added the template above.

Comment: How did you add {{ project.id }} in your template?

Comment: I just added it above the form tag to see if it would show anything.

Answer (score 0):

Adding this to the views solved the issue:

```
class TodoCreateView(CreateView):
    model = ProjectTodo
    template_name = 'company_accounts/add_todo.html'
    fields = ['title', 'notes', 'status']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        project = get_object_or_404(Project, id=self.kwargs.get('pk'))
        todo = form.save(commit=False)
        todo.project = project
        todo.save()
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('project_detail', args=[self.kwargs.get('pk')])
```